# What is the correct way to remove a node from a tree managed by awesome_nested_set?

Tags: ruby, nodes, nested-sets

It is unclear how to correctly remove a node or set of nodes from a tree managed by awesome_nested_set.

Given a parent node and a child node, I've tried

parent.children.clear

however, this then leaves the tree in a state such that I can't re-add the child back to the parent object.

Do I have to explicitly null out all of the lft, rgt, and parent_id columns?

Comment: Further research shows that if I do child.update_attribute(:parent_id, nil) and reload both parent and child, that seems to work.

Comment: Current approach is child.update_attribute(:parent_id, nil); parent.reload  That seems to do it.  Anyone care to confirm or offer a better option?

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote:

> Further research shows that if I do `child.update_attribute(:parent_id, nil)` and reload both parent and child, that seems to work.

Comment: ([Answer converted from a comment to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments?rq=1)).